# Choosing Coins To Flip

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution

Suppose I have two coins, and I don't know what the probability of getting a heads is with either coin. I flip one 60 times, and get heads 36 times. I flip another 20 times, and get heads 18 times. Which coin should I flip next for the highest probability of getting a heads? And how do I answer this more generally (changing # of flips, heads, and increasing the # of coins and ranking them)?

I tried solving this problem using the Maximum Likelihood Estimation function for the Binomial Distribution, but it doesn't behave in a way that I found useful.

Edit:
The most extreme example would be to consider I have *hundreds* of coins, some have only been flipped once, and some have been flipped hundreds of times. How do I rank the coins in order to decide which ones would give me the greatest chance of picking heads? The practical situation I'm looking at actually resembles this situation, after some abstraction!

Comment: Note hat for the first, you can't discard the hypothesis that the coin is fair.  For the second you most certainly can.

Comment: To stress:  you need to take into account the sample size, not just the observed probability.  Getting three $H$ out of four tries is hardly impressive.  Getting $75$ out of $100$ is.

Comment: Maximum Likelihood seems irrelevant here as we have no idea what the distribution of possible probabilities might be.  I would go for crude statistics.  For the first coin you can not reasonably reject the hypothesis that the coin is fair (there's like a $7.7\%$ chance of getting at least $36$ Heads).  For the second, we can.  That's enough.  More broadly, you could test the null hypothesis "the first coin has a lower $H$ probability than the second."  Of course, you'll need to declare some confidence level, and you'll have to make some assumptions about the underlying distribution.

Comment: @lulu see the new edit from a couple minutes ago - I'm considering potentially hundreds of coins, and I'm interested in trying to find the most biased ones.

Comment: Should add:  if this is derived from a practical situation, then I'd expect that it was possible to make some sensible assumptions about the underlying distribution.

Comment: My crude method works fine for hundreds of coins.  Pick a confidence level (say $5\%$).  For each coin work out the highest Heads probability you can't reject.  Pick the coin that wins this contest.

Comment: The practical situation is, uhh, from competitive Pokemon. Players bring a team of 6 Pokemon to battles, and across tournaments hundreds of battles are played. There is data on the # of uses and wins of each possible Pokemon, and I'm interested in testing to see which ones perform the best/worst, and whether a winrate that deviates from 50% is significant or not. Say a Pokemon has 100 uses, maybe a 53% winrate isn't significant but a 57% one is... I want to know where the line is.

Comment: Even further, if I considered pairings of Pokemon on a team, and wanted to consider the pairing's usage and winrates, then I am dealing with larger data sets by an order of magnitude and simply looking by eye to see usage and winrates isn't necessarily enough to easily pick out the "best" pairings (which is something one of my friends asked for some time ago). Then I have hundreds of "coins" and I am interested in presenting the best few.

Comment: As I'd hope my comments make clear, win rate is simply not enough.  Sample size is critical.  A person who played once and won, just got lucky.  I'd prefer somebody who won $600$ trials out of $1000$.

Comment: For a widely played game, I'd expect skill to be roughly normally distributed.  Though I'd want to test that claim.

Comment: We're looking at the win rates of the pokemon (or pairings of pokemon) not the players. As an example, some of the most used pokemon in the tier have the following # of uses & winrates in the most recent set of tournaments: (86,62%), (74,55%), (63,57%). Technically, to do this properly we would first have to exclude from these numbers instances when both players brought a pokemon, but anyway... notwithstanding that, how do I show, for example, which ones would have an underlying winrate above 50% if an infinite number of games were played with that pokemon?

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to go through the particulars of your situation.  Real life problems always come down to the gory details.  I'd have thought that the crude approach I sketched should apply here.

Comment: @lulu "there's like a 7.7% chance of getting at least 36 Heads" - how did you calculate this? I think I could use this number? Like, for each coin I can say, here's the probability of getting at least this many heads based on the assumption of a fair coin?

Comment: Assume a fair coin.  Compute $\sum_{k=36}^{60} \binom {60}k\times 2^{-60}\sim .0775$.  You could also approximate with a normal distribution.

Comment: Quick approximation:  $\sigma=\sqrt {15}=3.87$ so you aren't even looking at a $2\sigma$ event.  No big deal.

Comment: By contrast, the second coin would have $\sigma =\sqrt {5}=2.24$ so you'd be looking at a $3.6\sigma$ event.  That's low probability.

Comment: Thanks @lulu that's a lot of help. I covered that stuff (e.g. normal approximation of the bin. distribution) in school years ago but I'd forgotten most of it and how to apply it / struggled to link it back to this question.

Answer (score 4):

To answer this question rigorously, you need some sort of prior belief about the types of coins in the world.

To illustrate this, consider the extreme example provided by lulu in a comment to this [answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit):

> suppose I flipped one coin a million times and it came up $H$ all but once. And then I flipped a second coin once and got $H$.

Suppose first that your prior belief about the world is that there are only two types of coins: fair coins and 100%-heads coins. With respect to this belief, we can be certain that the first coin is fair, and so it would be correct to prefer the second coin, which could be 100%-heads, and thus guaranteed to be at least as good as the first one.

However, if we modify our belief about the world to the belief that any given coin in the world has a heads-probability that uniformly falls in the range $[0, 1]$, then the first coin would be the better bet. I'll omit an exact calculation here. This similar [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/489061/2221) should give some hints on what the calculation would look like - there would be a (double)-integral over a triangular region under the line $y=x$ involved if trying to compute the probability that one coin is more biased than the other.

If you are not sure about the exact prior belief that underlies your problem, then you may be interested in some of the general strategies that appear in the [multi-armed bandit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit) literature. The multi-armed bandit problem supposes that you are given access to $n$ slot machines, and that at each step you choose a machine to play. At each subsequent step, you want to utilize the data you have seen so far in your ever-growing sample-size to determine which machine to play/replay next. This has a similar flavor to your problem, and the link lists some strategies, some of which have been proven to be optimal in some sense given various assumptions. A difference between the optimization task in the multi armed bandit context and yours is that in the multi armed bandit context, you are faced with a tension of *exploration* (gather more data) vs *exploitation* (maximize based on data seen so far), while in the way you phrased your problem, it sounds like the exploration phase is complete.

If you do a [Google search for "multi armed bandit weighted coins"](https://www.google.com/search?q=multi%20armed%20bandit%20weighted%20coin), you get a variety of links similar to your problem of interest.

Comment: Thanks, this does give a lot to look at! In the real-world situation I'm looking at (sorry, this is buried quite deep in the comments on the question), there is actually some tension between exploration and exploitation - but other people are doing most of the "exploration". There are other complexities too, which the question omits. The way I've phrased the question is trying to abstract things to a point where things are manageable on a mathematical level.